# Customize People Search Results

Tags: web-part, search

i want to edit my people search results but i can't do it. i want to show phone numbers , email or id of the users. how can i do that?

Comment: Did you try the People Search Core Results webpart? This webpart displays OOTB phone number and email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1:
http://www.sharepointology.com/development/customize-the-people-search-results-part-1/

Part 2:
http://www.sharepointology.com/development/customize-the-people-search-results-part-2/

Just requires some custom xslt on the search results page.